# 403 forbidden for presigned_url upload

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have 403 error when uploading presigned url

At first, I exec `s3.generate_presigned_post` in local

```
    temp = s3.generate_presigned_post(
        "my-resource-bucket-v","test"
    )
```

and get the `url` and `fields`

```
{'url': 'https://my-resource-bucket-v.s3.amazonaws.com/', 'fields': {'key': 'test', 'AWSAccessKeyId': 'AKIAZ3YPMLASV6736UA4', 'policy': 'eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjogIjIwMjItMDUtMDlUMDY6MDU6MTNaIiwgImNvbmRpdGlvbnMiOiBbeyJidWNrZXQiOiAic2kyLXMzLXNidS1qb2ItaHVudGluZy1keC10b2t5by1qeGMtc3RhdGljLXJlc291cmNlLXYifSwgeyJrZXkiOiAidGVzdCJ9XX0=', 'signature': 'F7E074YWIVwy4ZL2zXSv8YVTbyE='}}"
```

then I try this to upload

```
curl -v -X POST \
-F key="{'key': 'test', 'AWSAccessKeyId': 'AKIAZ3YPMLASV6736UA4', 'policy': 'eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjogIjIwMjItMDUtMDlUMDY6MTE6MjhaIiwgImNvbmRpdGlvbnMiOiBbeyJidWNrZXQiOiAic2kyLXMzLXNidS1qb2ItaHVudGluZy1keC10b2t5by1qeGMtc3RhdGljLXJlc291cmNlLXYifSwgeyJrZXkiOiAidGVzdCJ9XX0=', 'signature': 'GNUthYj0cec9uIQjeJsuap7OTfk='}" \
-F policy="{'key': 'test', 'AWSAccessKeyId': 'AKIAZ3YPMLASV6736UA4', 'policy': 'eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjogIjIwMjItMDUtMDlUMDY6MTE6MjhaIiwgImNvbmRpdGlvbnMiOiBbeyJidWNrZXQiOiAic2kyLXMzLXNidS1qb2ItaHVudGluZy1keC10b2t5by1qeGMtc3RhdGljLXJlc291cmNlLXYifSwgeyJrZXkiOiAidGVzdCJ9XX0=', 'signature': 'GNUthYj0cec9uIQjeJsuap7OTfk='}" \
-F file=myimage.png https://my-resource-bucket-v.s3.amazonaws.com/
```

It returns like this.

It looks like uploading is success but denied by auth?

I think bucket policy of S3 is not relevant with `presigned_url`, So,, where the permission error occurs??

```
Note: Unnecessary use of -X or --request, POST is already inferred.
*   Trying 52.219.196.109:443...
* Connected to my-resource-bucket-v.s3.amazonaws.com (52.219.196.109) port 443 (#0)
* ALPN, offering h2
* ALPN, offering http/1.1
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*  CAfile: /etc/ssl/cert.pem
*  CApath: none
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Certificate (11):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (OUT), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS change cipher, Change cipher spec (1):
* TLSv1.2 (IN), TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using TLSv1.2 / ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256
* ALPN, server did not agree to a protocol
* Server certificate:
*  subject: CN=*.s3.amazonaws.com
*  start date: Dec 15 00:00:00 2021 GMT
*  expire date: Dec  3 23:59:59 2022 GMT
*  subjectAltName: host "my-resource-bucket-v.s3.amazonaws.com" matched cert's "*.s3.amazonaws.com"
*  issuer: C=US; O=Amazon; OU=Server CA 1B; CN=Amazon
*  SSL certificate verify ok.
> POST / HTTP/1.1
> Host: my-resource-bucket-v.s3.amazonaws.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.77.0
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 941
> Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------5a06682e8a44d108
> 
* We are completely uploaded and fine
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< x-amz-request-id: TBGPSXDQGM1JRAKV
< x-amz-id-2: NPU+clavFOAAUKCsc0wVb2Bi1Aeh86ce+k8J4vq6YSv+SCLC4bAzWSdbcgzhcYObU765goqg/Jw=
< Content-Type: application/xml
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Mon, 09 May 2022 05:17:55 GMT
< Server: AmazonS3
< 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
* Connection #0 to host my-resource-bucket-v.s3.amazonaws.com left intact
<Error><Code>AccessDenied</Code><Message>Access Denied</Message><RequestId>TBGPSXDQGM1JRAKV</RequestId><HostId>NPU+clavFOAAUKCsc0wVb2Bi1Aeh86ce+k8J4vq6YSv+SCLC4bAzWSdbcgzhcYObU765goqg/Jw=</HostId></Error>%
```

According to @BoarGules helps.

I set the bucket policy as like this below

```
    {
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": {
            "AWS": "*"
        },
        "Action": "s3:*",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::si2-s3-sbu-job-hunting-dx-tokyo-jxc-static-resource-v"
    },
```

Comment: *Access denied* in this context nearly always means exactly what it says. You say you "think bucket policy of S3 is not relevant". But some policy is getting in the way.

Comment: `https://my-resource-bucket-v/` is not a pre-signed url.

Comment: @BoarGules mmm , isee so I set bucket policy (adding article)

Comment: @Marcin
 Tha was my copy and paste mistake, I edited the article